# JTextField is getting immensely big although i tried to make it small

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, jtextfield

Hey guys this JTextField is getting immensely big but i set the prefered size to a small one. And also i want it after the JLabel that says enter first grade plus if you could just put the JLabels on top. Thanks a lot Stack, Love you Guys!!!

Here is the image of the run.

And here is my Code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ClickedTimes implements ActionListener {

    JFrame Frame;
    JPanel Panel;
    JButton Anwser;
    JLabel Label;
    JLabel Label2;
    JLabel Label3;
    JTextField Text1;
    JTextField Text2;
    JTextField Text3;
    JLabel SpaceLabel;
    public int count=1;
    Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
    Font font;

    public ClickedTimes() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        Frame = new JFrame("First Box-Layout");

        Panel = new JPanel();
        Frame.add(Panel);
        Panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2,14,12));
        Panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(Panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        Panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,150)));


        font = new Font("Times New Roman" , Font.BOLD , 20);
        Text1 = new JTextField(0);

        Label = new JLabel("Enter First Grade");

        Label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 0, 30, 20));
        Text1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(3,2));
        Label.setFont(font);
        Panel.add(Text1);
        Panel.add(Label);



        Label2 = new JLabel("Enter Second Grade");
        Label2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,2,20,0));
        Label2.setFont(font);
        Panel.add(Label2);


        Label3 = new JLabel("Enter Third Grade");
        Label3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,2,50,0));
        Label3.setFont(font);
        Panel.add(Label3);


        Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Frame.setResizable(false);
        Frame.setSize(500,500);
        Frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    private static void runGUI() {
         JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
         ClickedTimes greeting = new ClickedTimes();
         }
         public static void main(String[] args) {
         /* Methods that create and show a GUI should be
         run from an event-dispatching thread */
         javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
         runGUI();
         }
         });
         }
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String eventname = event.getActionCommand();

            if(eventname.equals("Anwser")){

                Label2.setText("To Get To The Other Side");
            }


        }


}
```

***EDIT:***

I did the gridbag layout but still didnt work with text field:

Without TextField(Fine):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY3uH.png)

With TextField(Not Fine):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mfeD.png)

Here is the code For that:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ClickedTimes implements ActionListener {

    JFrame Frame;
    JPanel Panel;
    JButton Anwser;
    JLabel Label;
    JLabel Label2;
    JLabel Label3;
    JTextField Text1;
    JTextField Text2;
    JTextField Text3;
    JLabel SpaceLabel;
    public int count=1;
    Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
    Font font;

    public ClickedTimes() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        Frame = new JFrame("First Box-Layout");

        Panel = new JPanel();
        Frame.add(Panel);
        Panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,100,400,-900));
        Panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,150)));


        font = new Font("Times New Roman" , Font.BOLD , 20);
        Text1 = new JTextField(0);

        Label = new JLabel("Enter First Grade");

        Label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 0, 30, 20));
        Text1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(3,2));
        Label.setFont(font);
        Panel.add(Text1);
        Panel.add(Label);



        Label2 = new JLabel("Enter Second Grade");
        Label2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,2,20,0));
        Label2.setFont(font);
        Panel.add(Label2);


        Label3 = new JLabel("Enter Third Grade");
        Label3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,2,50,0));
        Label3.setFont(font);
        Panel.add(Label3);


        Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Frame.setResizable(false);
        Frame.setSize(500,500);
        Frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    private static void runGUI() {
         JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
         ClickedTimes greeting = new ClickedTimes();
         }
         public static void main(String[] args) {
         /* Methods that create and show a GUI should be
         run from an event-dispatching thread */
         javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
         runGUI();
         }
         });
         }
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String eventname = event.getActionCommand();

            if(eventname.equals("Anwser")){

                Label2.setText("To Get To The Other Side");
            }


        }


}
```

Comment: You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: Huh? Is my code not organized sir?

Comment: @Universe You should look into naming conventions... variables with start with lowercase letters and camel case things and stuff like that.

Comment: @3kings Oh my bad! I tottaly forgot Putting the variables on camelcase sorry!

Comment: You don't need to just to make it more readable..

Comment: You cant read my code..?

Comment: It's a matter of quickly and easily understanding your code. fOr eXamPLE eNglisH is nOT aS eAsy tO pArSe if capItalIzAtIon iS dOne iNapProprIatly

Comment: Im not a programmer nor im a adult, so im not expected to have code that is highlyy organized. Its just a question. I would love if you guys can anwser it...

Comment: `BoxLayout` is influnced by minimumSize, maximumSize AND preferredSize.  Try addjusting both the `preferredSize` and `maximumSize` ... or just use `GridBagLayout`

Comment: `"Im not a programmer nor im a adult, so im not expected to have code that is highlyy organized"` -- understand that we're all volunteers. Regardless if you're a child or just starting out, we greatly appreciate it if you would in the future strive to make it as easy as possible to help you. That's not asking too much, is it?

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Ok ima look in to it and will respond with my success. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Edited it with my progress @MadProgrammer But still didnt work with textfield look at the Edited Post! Again Thanks! Would love if somone could help me!

Comment: So where are you setting the textfield's maximumSize?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Um let me set the textfields maximize sorry!

Comment: @MadProgrammer Same thing as the one i posted above with the textfield happenes when i put these lines of code:  Text1.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
  Text1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1, 1));

Answer (score 0):

`BoxLayout` is influnced by the components `minimumSize`, `maximumSize` and `preferredSize`.

So, from what I can tell, `BoxLayout` is trying to use the `JTextField`'s `maximumSize`, so you need to change it, probably to the match the field's `preferredSize`, for example...

[image: BoxLayout]

```
    Panel = new JPanel();
    Frame.add(Panel);
    Panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(Panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    Panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 150)));

    font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 20);
    Text1 = new JTextField(0);
    Text1.setMaximumSize(Text1.getPreferredSize());
```

Comment: Thank you so much MadProgrammer? If its not much do you know how to put them together in the same X Axis but a little Apart(Space). Again Thanks!!

Comment: I'd consider using a `GridBagLayout`, it's more flexible (this is just my opinion).  Take a look at [How to Use BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) and [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details